# Помогите понять логику функцию strtotime

Tags: php, функции

почему так происходит?

```
strtotime('01.02.2005') = 1107205200
strtotime('01/02/2005') = 1104613200
```

Comment: в мануале же всё описано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая дата читается как "месяц/день/год"

Из [мануала](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php):

> если разделителем является слэш (/), то дата интерпретируется в
>   американском формате m/d/y, если же разделителем является дефис (-)
>   или точка (.), то подразумевается использование европейского формата
>   d-m-y.